# Posting a label value based on ID using ajax to a php file to store them in a database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have to post the value of a label in a html, i used ajax to post them, into a php file, who's supossed to store the variables in a database, the php file seems to work, but the ajax script doesn't post the variables to the php file "InsertOrder", i don't know what am i doing wrong, i am new to programming in general and i am stuck, please help.

I have the following code:

```
function insertar(){
 
    var num_mesa = 5;
    var articulo = $("#lbl-cant-c")[0].innerHtml;
    var cantidad = $("#lbl-foot-c"[0].innerHtml);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insertarpedido.php",
        data:{ num_mesa: num_mesa, articulo: articulo, cantidad:cantidad },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (result){
            console.log("result");
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
```

And the HTML code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mdl-pedido" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content sn-fn-mdl">
            <div class="modal-body">
                Son <label id="lbl-cant-c"></label> <label id="lbl-foot-c"></label>?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" onclick="insertar()" name="save" class="btn bg-blue text-white btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mdl-mensaje">Si, agregar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn bg-orange text-white btn-lg btn-block" data-dismiss="modal">No, corregir</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see `lbl-cant-c` and `lbl-foot-c` are the labels who hold the value that I want to post.

Comment: Syntax error: `var cantidad = $("#lbl-foot-c"[0].innerHtml);`

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why aren't you using the `.text()` method?

Comment: Am I missing something? Those 2 labels do not contain anything _IS IT ME?_

Comment: Well, yes, they contain something, but i just put the modal code in the post.